# The request failed with HTTP status 415

Tags: wcf, c#-2.0, basichttpbinding

I am getting an exception when I try to call method from WCF...I am consuming WCF in windows application using framework 2.0 and my WCF uses the BasicHttpBinding option...

> The request failed with HTTP status
>   415: Cannot process the message
>   because the content type 'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected
>   type 'multipart/related;
>   type="application/xop+xml"'

Comment: `using framework 2.0` what? .NET 2.0 does not support WCF, are using it as a web service?

Answer (score 0):

The client application is failing as it sends data on an Endpoint which is expecting MTOM messages. However, the client application just sends plain Soap messages (Soap1.1). If you can't upgrade your client application to use .Net Framework 3.5, you can use WSE 3.0 which allows to use MTOM with .net framework 2.0.

If you can upgrade application to 3.5, you can use WCF to communicate to service.

Regards,
Amit Bhatia

Comment: thx 4 ur rply Amit. but if i upgrade my application and reference WCF as web service it still doesnt work...but if i reference it as service then it works...my requirement is tht my client has to be in framework 2.0 the only option i have is to reference WCF as web service...any suggestion on this?